# linq with max date in sub query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to select a record that joins to another table with status and an insert DateTime.  I want the record that corresponds to the AgreementStatuses with the maximum Date_Created

```
from c in Agreements 
    join a in AgreementStatuses on c.Agreements_ID equals a.Agreements_ID
    join s in Statuses on a.Statuses_ID equals s.Statuses_ID
where DateTime.Now > c.BeginDate
    && DateTime.Now < c.TermDate
    && c.ControlPlan_ID == 31
    && s.StatusText == "Promoted"
    && c.AlphaPrefix == "PEH"
    && c.States_ID == 33
    && a.Date_Created == (from n in AgreementStatuses  //ERROR HERE
        join y in Statuses on n.Statuses_ID equals y.Statuses_ID
        where y.StatusText == "Promoted"
        && n.Agreements_ID == 584
        group n by n.Agreements_ID into g
        select new {Date_Created = g.Max(t=>t.Date_Created)}).FirstOrDefault()
select c
```

error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and '<anonymous type: DateTime Date_Created>'
```

Comment: from sub query you select `anonymous object` : `new {Date_Created = g.Max(t=>t.Date_Created)}` and this isn't `DateTime` object... so `==` cannot be applied

Comment: You do not need new on last line : select g.Max(t=>t.Date_Created)}).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jdweng.  That did it.

```
from c in Agreements 
    join a in AgreementStatuses on c.Agreements_ID equals a.Agreements_ID
    join s in Statuses on a.Statuses_ID equals s.Statuses_ID
where DateTime.Now > c.BeginDate
    && DateTime.Now < c.TermDate
    && c.ControlPlan_ID == 31
    && s.StatusText == "Promoted"
    && c.AlphaPrefix == "PEH"
    //&& c.States_ID == 33
    && a.Date_Created == (from n in AgreementStatuses 
        join y in Statuses on n.Statuses_ID equals y.Statuses_ID
        where y.StatusText == "Promoted"
        && n.Agreements_ID == a.Agreements_ID
        group n by n.Agreements_ID into g
        select g.Max(t=>t.Date_Created)).FirstOrDefault()
select c
```